# Is it a good idea writing multiple aggregate in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My schema looks like this

```
{
    _id: ObjectID,
    gender: "MALE", // MALE or FEMALE
    status: "ACTIVE", // ACTIVE or INACTIVE
    method: "A" // A or B
}
```

The API needs to return a total document count, total count by gender, total count by status and total count by method. My current approach is making multiple `aggregate` calls and one `count` method.

As such,

```
const genderCursor = db.collection(Collection.Sample).aggregate([
    {"$group": { _id: "$gender", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
]);

const statusCursor = db.collection(Collection.Sample).aggregate([
    {"$group": { _id: "$status", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
]);

const methodCursor = db.collection(Collection.Sample).aggregate([
    {"$group": { _id: "$method", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
]);

const total = await db.collection(Collection.Sample).count();
await genderCursor.forEach(x => gender.push({ name: x._id, count: x.count}))
await statusCursor.forEach(x => statuses.push({ name: x._id, count: x.count}))
await methodCursor.forEach(x => methods.push({ name: x._id, count: x.count}))
```

Results,

```
{
    "total": 100,
    "gender": [
        {
            "name": "MALE",
            "count": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "FEMALE",
            "count": 70
        },
    ],
    "statuses": [
        {
            "name": "APPROVED",
            "count": 81
        },
        {
            "name": "CREATED",
            "count": 19
        },
    ],
    "methods": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "count": 50
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "count": 50
        },
    ],
}
```

Is there a better and cost effective method to achieve the same thing as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine all the queries into a single Aggregation Query since it will reduce your network roundtrip times and load on MongoDB servers.

There are two methods in doing this.

**Method-1: Using `null` Group**

You can group with `_id` null and apply `$cond` Operator. This is much
faster than the second method, but you have to apply all the outcomes required in the `$cond`.

> Choose whichever method works best for your use case.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "male": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$gender",
                "MALE"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          },
        },
      },
      "female": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$gender",
                "FEMALE"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          },
        }
      },
      "active": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status",
                "ACTIVE"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          },
        }
      },
      "inactive": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status",
                "INACTIVE"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          }
        },
      },
      "methodA": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$method",
                "A"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          },
        }
      },
      "methodB": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$method",
                "B"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,
          },
        },
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/475WrLcwi-w)

**Method-2: Using `$facet`**
You can also use the `$facet` stage, but it requires more computation on MongoDB compared with `$group`, but you don't have to write all the outcomes manually.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "gender": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$gender",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      "status": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$status",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      "method": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$method",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
      ],
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zb0pxrFUmkx)